# Python - Collect data from APIs, Cache and Push To DB - in Parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm

I'm having a hard time figuring it out how to develop the phase 3 of this algorithm:

1. Fetch data from a series of APIs
2. Store the data in the script until a certain condition is reached (cache and don't disturb the DB)
3. Push that structured data to a database AND at the same time continue with 1 (launch 1 without wait to complete the upload on the DB, the two things should go in parallel)

   ```
   import requests
   import time
   from sqlalchemy import schema, types
   from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
   import threading 

   # I usually work on postgres
   meta = schema.MetaData(schema="example")

   # table one
   table_api_one =    schema.Table('api_one', meta,
                      schema.Column('id', types.Integer, primary_key=True),                        
                      schema.Column('field_one', types.Unicode(255), default=u''),
                      schema.Column('field_two', types.BigInteger()),
                 )
   # table two
   table_api_two =    schema.Table('api_two', meta,
                      schema.Column('id', types.Integer, primary_key=True),                        
                      schema.Column('field_one', types.Unicode(255), default=u''),
                      schema.Column('field_two', types.BigInteger()),
                 )

   # create tables
   engine = create_engine("postgres://......", echo=False, pool_size=15, max_overflow=15)
   meta.bind = engine
   meta.create_all(checkfirst=True)

   # get the data from the API and return data as JSON
   def getdatafrom(url):
       data = requests.get(url)
       structured = data.json()    
       return structured 

   # push the data to the DB
   def flush(list_one,list_two):
       connection = engine.connect()
       # both lists are list of json
       connection.execute(table_api_one.insert(),list_one) 
       connection.execute(table_api_two.insert(),list_two) 
       connection.close()

   # start doing something
   def main():
       timesleep = 30
       flush_limit = 10
       threading.Timer(timesleep * flush_limit, main).start()
       data_api_one = []
       data_api_two = []

       # repeat the process 10 times (flush_limit) avoiding to keep to busy the DB  
       WHILE len(data_api_one) > flush_limit AND len(data_api_two) > flush_limit:
            data_api_one.append(getdatafrom("http://www.apiurlone.com/api...").copy())
            data_api_two.append(getdatafrom("http://www.apiurltwo.com/api...").copy())
            time.sleep(timesleep)

       # push the data when the limit is reached
       flush(data_api_one,data_api_two)

   # start the example
   main()
   ```

In this example script, the thread is launched every 10 * 30 sec a main() (avoid overlapping the threads)
but, for this algorithm during the time of the flush() the script stop collecting the data from the APIs.

How it's possible to flush and keep getting the data from the APIs continuously?

thanks!

Comment: I think you should run table1 and table2 operations in separate Python processes if you want this to scale

Comment: are you referring to the flush() function? how do you suggest to operate?

Comment: I'm talking about the entire thing. You can have a one generic block of code that only talks to one table and reads from one API. Then you can run multiple processes, not threads of that

Comment: Does this need to be done in Python? There are tools out there like Apache Nifi that can generally do what you're wanting here plus more

Comment: yeah! thank you. it seems stupid but I'm figuring out to code by trying, testing and making errors, and sometimes like now I totally miss the big picture. yeah, it will be simpler in that way.

Comment: @cricket_007 Well, no. I'm not good in any language why I should stick just with one. It seems a visual interface where you can design process of data acquisition.  Pretty interesting. In my example code, I've really oversimplified the workflow. Once i've collected the data I'm elaborating the data to produce new information and store this again to the DB. I don't know how to handle this with Apache Nifi. Maybe I should do with postgres.

Comment: Nifi is primarily in Java, but you can develop custom processes behind that web interface. My point was that you can get http json content, extract things, and dump them into a database 1) with little to no programming 2) in very parallel fashion

Comment: I really like your suggestions. thank you. I will dig in both directions,  testing Nifi and also understanding how to handle Consumer-Producer problems with python. It's not just a one-time issue, I need to learn this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155046/discussion-between-stefano-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0):

Usual approach is a `Queue` object (from module named `Queue` or `queue`, depending on Python version).

Create a producer function (running in one thread) which collects api data and when flushing `put`s it in the queue and a consumer function running in another thread waiting to `get` the data from the queue and store it to the database.

Comment: Tnx for your reply. And thanks for giving a name to my issue "Consumer-Producer problem". Yeah, more or less I've thought something similar but I've problems in making this working.